# Class Conversion outside of class declaration

Tags: c++, type-conversion, operator-keyword

Simple question I hope.

Is it possible to define a class conversion (equal operator) outside of either class?

This is stemming from an "api" like layer in my library. So I can compile select code based on the lower level library.

Example:

foo.hpp (this is my source)

```
class foo
{
}
```

bar.hpp (this not my source)

```
class bar
{
}
```

conversions.hpp (this file changes based on the linked low level layer)

```
bar operator=(const foo& other)
{
}
```

The operator will throw a compiler error since it's in a static context and should be declared inside a class declaration. This isn't really an option since that bar class can change.

Answer (score 0):

You can define an implicit conversion operation in `foo`:

```
class foo
{
 public:
 operator bar() const
 {
  //make bar from this foo
 }
};
```

You can now do these:

```
bar b = foo();//b gets copy-initialized using the implicit conversion above
b = foo();//Since bar doesn't have an operator=(const foo&), standard conversions would apply. The user-defined foo to bar conversion kicks in followed by a bar copy/move.
```

Comment: The problem with this is that the bar class can change depending on the platform the code is compiled for. For example lets say on linux there is bar, but on windows there is bar2. I am trying to avoid conditional compiling such as using #ifdef LINUX for example. I plan to use different makefile rules for compiling certain source code that is platform dependent or just library dependent.

Comment: Lets suppose the restriction on `operator=` being a non-static member was removed. How does that help you avoid conditional compilation?